# flask jquery ajax call that is executing on every loop

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I want to iterate over files in a folder and and render links that execute a file from a flask interface.

The html/js I wrote executes the file selected by the user as many times as there are files in the folder.  where do i need to be more specific so it only executes once?

```
 {% for item in restartFiles %} 

<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a.calculate').bind('click', function() {
       var item = $(this).attr('id');

      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/restartajax/'+item, {
      }, function(data) {

        $("span.result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<h4>{{item}}</h4>
   <span class="result">?</span>
<p><a href=# name = a class="calculate" id="{{ item }}">restart {{ item }}</a>
</div>
 {%endif%} {%endfor%}
```

**The view, just in case**

```
@app.route('/restartajax/<computer>')
def restartajax(computer):
    def runJob(computer):
        try:
            subprocess.call(r"\\covenas\decisionsupport\meinzer\production\bat\restart\%s" % computer)
        except Exception,e:
            print 'there was an exception', e
    thr = Thread(target = runJob, args = [computer])
    thr.start()
    return jsonify(result="restarting "+computer+" please wait 10 minutes")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed your `<script>` tag inside a for loop. Move it outside the loop, preferably after the loop.

```
{% for item in restartFiles %} 

<h4>{{item}}</h4>
<span class="result">?</span>
<p><a href=# name = a class="calculate" id="{{ item }}">restart {{ item }}</a>
</div>
{%endif%} {%endfor%}

// THE SCRIPT IS NOW HERE
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
    $('a.calculate').bind('click', function() {
    var item = $(this).attr('id');

    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/restartajax/'+item, {
    }, function(data) {

        $("span.result").text(data.result);
    });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: oh my!  I've been staring at it for too long.  thank you so much.

Comment: often did I make that mistake